# How to close ShowModelDialog box from code behind

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am creating a custom button in ribbon bar for share point 2010. For the button I have mentioned some code in JavaScript. When the custom ribbon button is clicked I have made to open a show model dialog box and inside the model dialog box I have displayed a aspx page which contain buttons. My requirement is if I click the button in aspx page I want to close the show dialog box.

Can anyone guide me for this situation

This is my code snippet for the custom button click .

```
           url: '/_layouts/FileUpload/Application.aspx',              
            allowMaximize: false,
            showClose: true,
            width: 620,
            height: 208,

            };
```

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);"/>

Regards,
Zakeer Ahamed.S

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
    public static void CloseForm(Page form, string redirectUrl)
    {
        if (SPContext.Current.IsPopUI)
        {
            form.Response.Clear();
            form.Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose(1, '');</script>");
            form.Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            form.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To close a dialog box from code behind you can use:

```
this.Page.Response.Clear();

        if (succes)
        {
            this.Page.Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose(1, 'saved');</script>");
        }
        else
        {
            this.Page.Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose(0, 'cancelled');</script>");
        }

        this.Page.Response.End();
```

The parameters of commonModalDialogClose are dialogresult and returnvalue.

Comment: HI Anita Boerboom, Thanks for the update it work for me.